# When deploying mvc project with web reference in class library I see blank page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, windows-server-2008-r2

Hello I've got a mvc4 project with a web reference in a class library (Total two projects in my soluition).

SO what I've done so far to publish this project to my Windoiws 2008 r2 SERVER:

1. I give right - click only on my mvc web project -> Publish -> As publish method I choose -> file system -> and I give the physical path of the folder where i want to publish.
2. Then in my Internet Informatiobn Services Manager  - > i give new Site and I bind this site with the physical folder I've created

So my problem is that when I start the site I see just one blank page and nothing in it. So I have no clue for any excception.

Keep in mind that before trying to upload this project I've created one simple mvc project (without class library whith only one index action that returns simple view with hello world message) and I had no problem deploying that site. What may be the problem?  THANK YOU SO MUCH IN ADVANCE. I'm stuch with this for two days.

Answer (score 0):

1.check Application pool select ASP.NET v4.0 Classic then tray.